# Object does not save to Realm DB

Tags: android, realm

Realm initialization in OnCreate() void:

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Saving object to Realm DB void:

```
private void saveNote() {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.insert(note);
        }
    });
}
```

> Class Note extends RealmObject.

In the following code (in another activity) I try to get count of objects in DB, but I get 0:

```
private void getNotesFromRealm() {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    final RealmResults realmResults = realm.where(Note.class).findAll();
    Log.d("realm", "" + realmResults.size());
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

> 2020-07-08 12:17:36.581 19576-19576/com.myapps.notes D/realm: 0

P.S: Note class here:

```
public class Note extends RealmObject {
private int id;
@RealmField(name = "name")
private String name;
private String year, month, day, hour, minute, text;

public Note() {}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
Note(String name, String year, String month, String day, String hour, String minute) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

String getYear() {
    return year;
}

void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}

String getDay() {
    return day;
}

void setDay(String day) {
    this.day = day;
}
```

}

Comment: Please share Note class

Comment: also the note object creation

Comment: note = new Note();
After that all fields (exept ID) are set using setters

Comment: @kirvel try with this code `realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
    val user = realm.createObject(User::class.java)
    user.name = "John"
    user.email = "john@corporation.com"
}`

Answer (score 0):

You should create `Note` object like below:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Note note = realm.createObject(Note.class);
note.setName("Kirvel");
.....
......
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Also, initialize `Realm` in `application` class as below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Initialize Realm. Should only be done once when the application starts.
        Realm.init(this);

        // In this example, no default configuration is set,
        // so by default, `RealmConfiguration.Builder().build()` is used.
    }
}
```

Comment: Still get 0-size. Maybe there is a problem with following code in another activity?
       


        realm.beginTransaction();
        final RealmResults realmResults = realm.where(Note.class).findAll();
        Log.d("realm", "" + realmResults.size());
        realm.commitTransaction();

Comment: where you are initialising Realm? in activity, then move it to the application class Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

Comment: I install Realm the same way in both activities: Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

Comment: I think  you should do in one place, that's Application class. please try

Comment: I found out what caused a mistake.
I started a new Activity before I saved data in Realm DB.
Very stupid mistake)
Thank you for your help)